# Videogular vg-controls plugin position under the video

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, padding, videogular

sound quite easy but at the moment I don't find a solution for it. I simply try to get the vg-controls plugin positioning under the video.

Because I am using the Plugin in Ionic, it is not so usability-friendly when the vg-controls autohide or something. Therefore I like to bringt the vg-controls container under the video-container.

But for now it is always in the video, and only a padding-top is doing the job. But not the full job, because with a padding it is not fully responsive and always depends on the display of the smartphone.

Has anybody a simple solution for this? I use the regular code from the website-tutorials:
[enter link description here](http://www.videogular.com/examples/controls-plugin/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, fixed it with simple css code.

Height of vg-controls is 50px, adding a margin-top to the vg-controls-container. Done.

Thanks anyway ;)